# Function declared in openssl/sha.h but not found in shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld, libssl

I've tried to link my C program against `libssl.so`, but the linker fails to find a function in that library that does exist in the header file.

Makefile target code:

```
$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -lssl -lmagic
```

Output:

```
...
/usr/bin/ld: obj/signature.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SHA256_Init@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

The function is `SHA256_Init()` and it is present in `openssl/sha.h` that it included in the source file.

I'm on Debian 9. I have the following packages installed: `libssl1.0.0`, `libssl1.0.2`, `libssl1.1`, `libssl-dev` (1.1.0).

```
$ la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl*
-rw-r--r-- root root 357024 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
-rw-r--r-- root root 738444 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx root root     13 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- root root 395176 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- root root 431232 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
-rw-r--r-- root root 442920 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```

What am I doing wrong and how to solve the problem?

Comment: What does `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so | grep SHA256` show?

Comment: @Barmar, `U SHA256_Init` and `U SHA256_Transform`.

Comment: I think the `@@OPENSSL_1_1_0` is significant. I'm not sure where that's coming from, it looks like it might be something like C++ name mangling.

Comment: How was `signature.o` compiled?

Comment: @Barmar, `$(CC) -c -o ./obj/signature.o ./src/signature.c -I./inc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL is split into 2 libraries, libssl and libcrypto, these functions live in libcrypto, so you don't need to link to libssl. Use

```
 -lcrypto
```

You should also read this [documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) for more info, e.g. how to properly initialize libcrypto